# Is it possible to make scripts to automatically install programs?

Tags: scripts

I have some programs that I like in Ubuntu and some that I don't like. Is it possible to make a script to my memory stick such that it removes those programs I don't need and installs those I do need? For example, remove Gnome and Gedit, install Xfce, Kate, Texlive-base, and Okular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a script in a text editor, adding the sequence of `apt-get` commands you want to execute:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get remove --purge gnome gedit ...
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get install xfce4 kate texlive-base ...
```

Then save the file. Now you can run it in a terminal (assuming you've saved it in your home directory):

```
[username@localhost ~] $ sudo sh my-script.sh
```